# How to see click-to-play exceptions list in Firefox

Tags: firefox

I have some plugins in Firefox set to "Ask to activate" and Firefox let's me "Allow and remember" for specific sites. Is there a view where I can see currently "remembered" sites? I know that I can go to one of the sites and click the plugin icon in the URL bar to see if it is allowed (and also block it from there), but I'd like to see a list of all the sites I have currently allowed.